# FasterXML jackson-dataformat-xml serialization version and encoding not added to xml

Tags: java, xml, fasterxml

Hi I am serializing java POJO object to xml using faster-xml(https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki ).When i do that i got xml but it doesn't have any version and encoding in xml file.This is the format i need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SampleRequest>
... 
</SampleRequest>
```

But I got Only this one

```
<SampleRequest>
... 
</SampleRequest>
```

Is there any configuration need to be added in jackson fasterxml anotation.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can configure your `XmlMapper` to write the XML header.

```java
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.configure( ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true );
```

As an example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Xml {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     // Important: create XmlMapper; it will use proper factories, workarounds
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
        xmlMapper.writeValue(System.out, new SampleRequest());
    }
}

class SampleRequest{
    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 2;
}
```

This generates the output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SampleRequest>
   ...
</SampleRequest>
```

In case you want to set the version to *1.1* instead of *1.0*, use `ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_1_1`.

Notice that Faster-XML team [recommends](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/tree/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.10.0#maven-dependency) to use [Woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox) library. In case you use it, some other configurations can be set. Among all of them there is one related to setting double quotes:

```java
public static final String P_USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES_IN_XML_DECL="com.ctc.wstx.useDoubleQuotesInXmlDecl";
```

at [WstxOutputProperties.java](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ctc/wstx/api/WstxOutputProperties.java)

For more details check out [configuring Woodstox parser](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/configuring-woodstox-xml-parser-woodstox-specific-properties-1ce5030a5173).

Comment: Do you know how I can set the standalone directive?

Comment: How did you get it using double-quotes? Mine has defaulted to single-quotes.

Comment: I think that this could be related to xml underlying implementation, what dependencies are you using?

Comment: @StuartClark did you ever figure out how to get the standalone directive?

Comment: @PunDefeated sorry I may have done but was a few years back now can't remember what project I even asked the question for, best of luck!

Comment: please can someone tell how to get double quotes instead of single quotes here ?

Answer (score 8):

For those wondering how to change single quotes to double quotes:

```
String propName = com.ctc.wstx.api.WstxOutputProperties.P_USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES_IN_XML_DECL;
xmlMapper.getFactory()
         .getXMLOutputFactory()
         .setProperty(propName, true);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import com.ctc.wstx.api.WstxOutputProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;

@Configuration
public class XmlConfig {
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(true).build();
        xmlMapper.enable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION);
        xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty(WstxOutputProperties.P_USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES_IN_XML_DECL, true);
        return new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(xmlMapper);
    }
}
```